# for and else, dont insert data in the database if the if condition its true

Tags: java, mysql

i hope someone can help me, im trying to not execute a "else" thats its in the bottom of this code, but first i have a for, that has a if, and if the if its true, the rest of the code after de for dont have to works, but i dont know how to do it or where place the for or the else

Basically, i want to stop all the code after the for if the condition inside the for its true

I leave a piece of the code down below, i hope you guys can help me

```
private void btnINGRESARActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        
        for(int i=0;i<tbl_hps.getRowCount();i++){
        if (tbl_hps.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(txt_n_hp.getText())){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "HP YA ESTA REGISTRADO, INGRESE OTRO ID");
           modelo.removeRow(i);
           
        }
        
        }
        
        this.mostrarDatos();
        
        
        if (txt_n_hp.getText().isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "INGRESE N° DE HP",
                "OPERACION FALLIDA",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
             
            }

        if (txtnombre_hp.getText().isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "INGRESE NOMBRE DE HP",
                "OPERACION FALLIDA",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
             
            }

        if (txtvolumen.getText().isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "INGRESE VOLUMEN DE HP",
                "OPERACION FALLIDA",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
             
            }

        if (txttipo_hormigon.getText().isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "INGRESE TIPO DE HORMIGON",
                "OPERACION FALLIDA",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
             
            }

        if (txtcemento1_m3.getText().isEmpty() ||  txtpsi_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtfiller_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtfibra1_m3.getText().isEmpty()||
                txtfibra2_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtarena1_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtarena2_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtgrava20mm_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtgrava40mm_m3.getText().isEmpty()||
                txtadi1_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtadi2_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtadi3_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtadi4_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtagua_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtdiferenciagua_m3.getText().isEmpty()){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "INGRESE AL MENOS UN MATERIAL",
                    "OPERACION FALLIDA",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                txtcemento1_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                
                txtpsi_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtfiller_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtfibra1_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtfibra2_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtarena1_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtarena2_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtgrava20mm_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtgrava40mm_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtadi1_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtadi2_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtadi3_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtadi4_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtagua_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                txtdiferenciagua_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                 
            }
      
        else { //THIS IS THE ELSE I DONT WANT TO EXECUTE IF THE IF INSIDE THE FOR ITS TRUE
                
                conexion objConexion = new conexion();

                TRANSEX oTRANSEX = recuperarDatosGUI();

                String strSentenciaInsert = String.format("insert into hp (ID_HP,NOMBRE_HP,ENSAYO,DIA,MES,ANO,TIPO_HORMIGON,"
                    /*M3*/
                    + "CEMENTO1_M3,PSI_M3,FILLER_M3,FIBRA1_M3,FIBRA2_M3,ARENA_M3,ARENA2_M3,GRAVILLA_M3,GRAVA_M3,ADITIVO1_M3,ADITIVO2_M3,ADITIVO3_M3,ADITIVO4_M3,AGUA_M3,DIFERENCIA_AGUA_M3,"

                    /*SECOS*/
                    + "CEMENTO1_SECOS,PSI_SECOS,FILLER_SECOS,FIBRA1_SECOS,FIBRA2_SECOS,ARENA1_SECOS,ARENA2_SECOS,GRAVILLA_SECOS,GRAVA_SECOS,ADITIVO1_SECOS,ADITIVO2_SECOS,"
                        + "ADITIVO3_SECOS,ADITIVO4_SECOS,AGUA_SECOS,"
                    + "DIFERENCIA_AGUA_SECOS,"

                    /*HUMEDAD*/
                    + "CEMENTO1_HU,PSI_HU,FILLER_HU,FIBRA1_HU,FIBRA2_HU,ARENA1_HU,ARENA2_HU,GRAVILLA_HU,GRAVA_HU,ADITIVO1_HU,ADITIVO2_HU,ADITIVO3_HU,ADITIVO4_HU,AGUA_HU,DIFERENCIA_AGUA_HU,"

                    /*HUMEDOS*/
                    + "CEMENTO1_HUMEDOS,PSI_HUMEDOS,FILLER_HUMEDOS,FIBRA1_HUMEDOS,FIBRA2_HUMEDOS,ARENA_HUMEDOS,ARENA2_HUMEDOS,GRAVILLA_HUMEDOS,GRAVA_HUMEDOS,ADITIVO1_HUMEDOS,ADITIVO2_HUMEDOS,"
                        + "ADITIVO3_HUMEDOS,ADITIVO4_HUMEDOS,AGUA_HUMEDOS,DIFERENCIA_AGUA_HUMEDOS,PESO_MATERIAL,"
                    + "OBSERVACION1,OBSERVACION2,OBSERVACION3,OBSERVACION4,OBSERVACION5,OBSERVACION6,OBSERVACION7,OBSERVACION8,OBSERVACION9,OBSERVACION10,OBSERVACION11,OBSERVACION12,"
                    
                    /*MEDICIONES HORMIGON FRESCO*/    
                    + "CONO_PEDIDO,CONO_OBTENIDO,PESO_MUESTRA,VOLUMEN_TARRO,DENSIDAD,TEMP_HORMIGON,AIRE_OBTENIDO,VOLUMEN_RENDIDO,RENDIMIENTO,CEMENTO_REAL," 
                    + "AGUA_LIBRE_REAL,RAZON_AC,AGUA_LIBRE,AGUA_ABSORCION,AGUA_TOTAL,TEMP_AMBIENTE,HUMEDAD_RELATIVA, EXUDACION,SEGREGACION,"
                    + "FECHA1,FECHA2,FECHA3,FECHA4,FECHA5,FECHA6,FECHA7,FECHA8,FECHA9,DIAS1,DIAS2,DIAS3,DIAS4,DIAS5,DIAS6,DIAS7,DIAS8,DIAS9,DENSIDAD1,DENSIDAD2,DENSIDAD3,DENSIDAD4,DENSIDAD5,"
                    + "DENSIDAD6,DENSIDAD7,DENSIDAD8,DENSIDAD9,RUPTURA1,RUPTURA2,RUPTURA3,RUPTURA4,RUPTURA5,RUPTURA6,RUPTURA7,RUPTURA8,RUPTURA9,PROBETA1,PROBETA2,PROBETA3,PROBETA4,PROBETA5,"
                    + "PROBETA6,PROBETA7,PROBETA8,PROBETA9,RESISTENCIA1_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA2_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA3_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA4_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA5_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA6_PROBETA,"
                    + "RESISTENCIA7_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA8_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA9_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA1_MEDIA,RESISTENCIA2_MEDIA,RESISTENCIA3_MEDIA,TIEMPO1_CONO,TIEMPO2_CONO,TIEMPO3_CONO,"
                    + "ASENTAMIENTO1_CONO,ASENTAMIENTO2_CONO,ASENTAMIENTO3_CONO,INICIO,TERMINO,DELTA,HORA,VOLUMEN)values "

                    + "('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',"
                    + "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',"
                    + "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',"
                        + "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',"
                        + "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",

                    oTRANSEX.getID(),oTRANSEX.getNombre(),oTRANSEX.getEnsayo(),oTRANSEX.getDia(),
                    oTRANSEX.getMes(),oTRANSEX.getAno(),oTRANSEX.getTipo(),

                    /*M3*/
                    oTRANSEX.getCemento1_m3(), oTRANSEX.getPsi_m3(),oTRANSEX.getFiller_m3(),oTRANSEX.getFibra1_m3(),oTRANSEX.getFibra2_m3(),
                    oTRANSEX.getArena_m3(),oTRANSEX.getArena2_m3(),oTRANSEX.getGravilla_m3(),oTRANSEX.getGrava_m3(), oTRANSEX.getAditivo1_m3(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo2_m3(),
                    oTRANSEX.getAditivo3_m3(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo4_m3(),
                    oTRANSEX.getAguatotal_m3(),oTRANSEX.getDiferencia_agua_m3(),

                    /*SECOS*/
                    oTRANSEX.getCemento1_secos(),oTRANSEX.getPsi_secos(),oTRANSEX.getFiller_secos(),oTRANSEX.getFibra1_secos(),
                    oTRANSEX.getFibra2_secos(),oTRANSEX.getArena_secos(),oTRANSEX.getArena2_secos(),oTRANSEX.getGravilla_secos(),oTRANSEX.getGrava_secos(),
                    oTRANSEX.getAditivo1_secos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo2_secos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo3_secos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo4_secos(),oTRANSEX.getAguatotal_secos(),
                    oTRANSEX.getDiferencia_agua_secos(),

                    /*HUMEDAD*/
                    oTRANSEX.getCemento1_hu(),oTRANSEX.getPsi_hu(),oTRANSEX.getFiller_hu(),oTRANSEX.getFibra1_hu(),
                    oTRANSEX.getFibra2_hu(),oTRANSEX.getArena_hu(),oTRANSEX.getArena2_hu(),oTRANSEX.getGravilla_hu(),oTRANSEX.getGrava_hu(),
                    oTRANSEX.getAditivo1_hu(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo2_hu(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo3_hu(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo4_hu(),oTRANSEX.getAguatotal_hu(),oTRANSEX.getDiferencia_agua_hu(),

                    /*HUMEDOS*/
                    oTRANSEX.getCemento1_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getPsi_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getFiller_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getFibra1_humedos(),
                    oTRANSEX.getFibra2_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getArena_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getArena2_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getGravilla_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getGrava_humedos(),
                    oTRANSEX.getAditivo1_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo2_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo3_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo4_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getAguatotal_humedos(),
                    oTRANSEX.getDiferencia_agua_humedos(),

                    /*PESO MATERIAL*/
                    oTRANSEX.getPeso_material(),

                    /*OBSERVACIONES*/

                    oTRANSEX.getObservacion1(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion2(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion3(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion4(),
                    oTRANSEX.getObservacion5(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion6(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion7(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion8(),
                    oTRANSEX.getObservacion9(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion10(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion11(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion12(),
                
                     /*MEDICIONES HORMIGON FRESCO*/   
                    oTRANSEX.getCono_pedido(),oTRANSEX.getCono_obtenido(),oTRANSEX.getPeso_muestra(),oTRANSEX.getVolumen_tarro(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad(),
                    oTRANSEX.getTemp_hormigon(),oTRANSEX.getAire_obtenido(),oTRANSEX.getVolumen_rendido(),oTRANSEX.getRendimiento(),
                    oTRANSEX.getCemento_real(),oTRANSEX.getAgua_libre_real(),oTRANSEX.getRazon_ac(),oTRANSEX.getAgua_libre(),
                    
                    oTRANSEX.getAgua_absorcion(),oTRANSEX.getAgua_total(),oTRANSEX.getTemp_ambiente(),oTRANSEX.getHumedad_relativa(),oTRANSEX.getExudacion(),
                    oTRANSEX.getSegregacion(),
                    
                    oTRANSEX.getFecha1(),oTRANSEX.getFecha2(),oTRANSEX.getFecha3(),oTRANSEX.getFecha4(),oTRANSEX.getFecha5(),oTRANSEX.getFecha6(),oTRANSEX.getFecha7(),
                    oTRANSEX.getFecha8(),oTRANSEX.getFecha9(),oTRANSEX.getDias1(),oTRANSEX.getDias2(),oTRANSEX.getDias3(),oTRANSEX.getDias4(),oTRANSEX.getDias5(),
                    oTRANSEX.getDias6(),oTRANSEX.getDias7(),oTRANSEX.getDias8(),oTRANSEX.getDias9(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad1(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad2(),
                    oTRANSEX.getDensidad3(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad4(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad5(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad6(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad7(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad8(),
                    oTRANSEX.getDensidad9(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura1(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura2(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura3(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura4(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura5(),
                    oTRANSEX.getRuptura6(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura7(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura8(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura9(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta1(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta2(),
                    oTRANSEX.getProbeta3(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta4(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta5(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta6(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta7(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta8(),
                    oTRANSEX.getProbeta9(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia1_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia2_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia3_probeta(),
                    oTRANSEX.getResistencia4_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia5_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia6_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia7_probeta(),
                    oTRANSEX.getResistencia8_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia9_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia1_media(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia2_media(),
                    oTRANSEX.getResistencia3_media(),oTRANSEX.getTiempo1_cono(),oTRANSEX.getTiempo2_cono(),oTRANSEX.getTiempo3_cono(),oTRANSEX.getAsentamiento1_cono(),
                    oTRANSEX.getAsentamiento2_cono(),oTRANSEX.getAsentamiento3_cono(),oTRANSEX.getInicio(),oTRANSEX.getTermino(),oTRANSEX.getDelta(),oTRANSEX.getHora(),
                    oTRANSEX.getVolumen());

                objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInsert);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "HP ingresado correctamente",
                    "OPERACION EXITOSA",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                
                
                
        }
        
        
        
        
                
       this.mostrarDatos();
        
    }
```

private void btnINGRESARActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    for(int i=0;i<tbl_hps.getRowCount();i++){
    if (tbl_hps.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(txt_n_hp.getText())){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "HP YA ESTA REGISTRADO, INGRESE OTRO ID");
       modelo.removeRow(i);
       
    }
    

    }
    //HERE I WANT TO STOP THE BUTTON FUNCTION IF THE IF INSIDE THE FOR ITS TRUE


    
    this.mostrarDatos();
    
    
    if (txt_n_hp.getText().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "INGRESE N° DE HP",
            "OPERACION FALLIDA",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         
        }

    if (txtnombre_hp.getText().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "INGRESE NOMBRE DE HP",
            "OPERACION FALLIDA",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         
        }

    if (txtvolumen.getText().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "INGRESE VOLUMEN DE HP",
            "OPERACION FALLIDA",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         
        }

    if (txttipo_hormigon.getText().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "INGRESE TIPO DE HORMIGON",
            "OPERACION FALLIDA",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         
        }

    if (txtcemento1_m3.getText().isEmpty() ||  txtpsi_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtfiller_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtfibra1_m3.getText().isEmpty()||
            txtfibra2_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtarena1_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtarena2_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtgrava20mm_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtgrava40mm_m3.getText().isEmpty()||
            txtadi1_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtadi2_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtadi3_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtadi4_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtagua_m3.getText().isEmpty()||txtdiferenciagua_m3.getText().isEmpty()){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "INGRESE AL MENOS UN MATERIAL",
                "OPERACION FALLIDA",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            txtcemento1_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            
            txtpsi_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtfiller_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtfibra1_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtfibra2_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtarena1_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtarena2_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtgrava20mm_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtgrava40mm_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtadi1_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtadi2_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtadi3_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtadi4_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtagua_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            txtdiferenciagua_m3.setText(String.valueOf(0));
             
        }
  
    else {
            
            conexion objConexion = new conexion();

            TRANSEX oTRANSEX = recuperarDatosGUI();

            String strSentenciaInsert = String.format("insert into hp (ID_HP,NOMBRE_HP,ENSAYO,DIA,MES,ANO,TIPO_HORMIGON,"
                /*M3*/
                + "CEMENTO1_M3,PSI_M3,FILLER_M3,FIBRA1_M3,FIBRA2_M3,ARENA_M3,ARENA2_M3,GRAVILLA_M3,GRAVA_M3,ADITIVO1_M3,ADITIVO2_M3,ADITIVO3_M3,ADITIVO4_M3,AGUA_M3,DIFERENCIA_AGUA_M3,"

                /*SECOS*/
                + "CEMENTO1_SECOS,PSI_SECOS,FILLER_SECOS,FIBRA1_SECOS,FIBRA2_SECOS,ARENA1_SECOS,ARENA2_SECOS,GRAVILLA_SECOS,GRAVA_SECOS,ADITIVO1_SECOS,ADITIVO2_SECOS,"
                    + "ADITIVO3_SECOS,ADITIVO4_SECOS,AGUA_SECOS,"
                + "DIFERENCIA_AGUA_SECOS,"

                /*HUMEDAD*/
                + "CEMENTO1_HU,PSI_HU,FILLER_HU,FIBRA1_HU,FIBRA2_HU,ARENA1_HU,ARENA2_HU,GRAVILLA_HU,GRAVA_HU,ADITIVO1_HU,ADITIVO2_HU,ADITIVO3_HU,ADITIVO4_HU,AGUA_HU,DIFERENCIA_AGUA_HU,"

                /*HUMEDOS*/
                + "CEMENTO1_HUMEDOS,PSI_HUMEDOS,FILLER_HUMEDOS,FIBRA1_HUMEDOS,FIBRA2_HUMEDOS,ARENA_HUMEDOS,ARENA2_HUMEDOS,GRAVILLA_HUMEDOS,GRAVA_HUMEDOS,ADITIVO1_HUMEDOS,ADITIVO2_HUMEDOS,"
                    + "ADITIVO3_HUMEDOS,ADITIVO4_HUMEDOS,AGUA_HUMEDOS,DIFERENCIA_AGUA_HUMEDOS,PESO_MATERIAL,"
                + "OBSERVACION1,OBSERVACION2,OBSERVACION3,OBSERVACION4,OBSERVACION5,OBSERVACION6,OBSERVACION7,OBSERVACION8,OBSERVACION9,OBSERVACION10,OBSERVACION11,OBSERVACION12,"
                
                /*MEDICIONES HORMIGON FRESCO*/    
                + "CONO_PEDIDO,CONO_OBTENIDO,PESO_MUESTRA,VOLUMEN_TARRO,DENSIDAD,TEMP_HORMIGON,AIRE_OBTENIDO,VOLUMEN_RENDIDO,RENDIMIENTO,CEMENTO_REAL," 
                + "AGUA_LIBRE_REAL,RAZON_AC,AGUA_LIBRE,AGUA_ABSORCION,AGUA_TOTAL,TEMP_AMBIENTE,HUMEDAD_RELATIVA, EXUDACION,SEGREGACION,"
                + "FECHA1,FECHA2,FECHA3,FECHA4,FECHA5,FECHA6,FECHA7,FECHA8,FECHA9,DIAS1,DIAS2,DIAS3,DIAS4,DIAS5,DIAS6,DIAS7,DIAS8,DIAS9,DENSIDAD1,DENSIDAD2,DENSIDAD3,DENSIDAD4,DENSIDAD5,"
                + "DENSIDAD6,DENSIDAD7,DENSIDAD8,DENSIDAD9,RUPTURA1,RUPTURA2,RUPTURA3,RUPTURA4,RUPTURA5,RUPTURA6,RUPTURA7,RUPTURA8,RUPTURA9,PROBETA1,PROBETA2,PROBETA3,PROBETA4,PROBETA5,"
                + "PROBETA6,PROBETA7,PROBETA8,PROBETA9,RESISTENCIA1_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA2_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA3_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA4_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA5_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA6_PROBETA,"
                + "RESISTENCIA7_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA8_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA9_PROBETA,RESISTENCIA1_MEDIA,RESISTENCIA2_MEDIA,RESISTENCIA3_MEDIA,TIEMPO1_CONO,TIEMPO2_CONO,TIEMPO3_CONO,"
                + "ASENTAMIENTO1_CONO,ASENTAMIENTO2_CONO,ASENTAMIENTO3_CONO,INICIO,TERMINO,DELTA,HORA,VOLUMEN)values "

                + "('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',"
                + "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',"
                + "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',"
                    + "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',"
                    + "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",

                oTRANSEX.getID(),oTRANSEX.getNombre(),oTRANSEX.getEnsayo(),oTRANSEX.getDia(),
                oTRANSEX.getMes(),oTRANSEX.getAno(),oTRANSEX.getTipo(),

                /*M3*/
                oTRANSEX.getCemento1_m3(), oTRANSEX.getPsi_m3(),oTRANSEX.getFiller_m3(),oTRANSEX.getFibra1_m3(),oTRANSEX.getFibra2_m3(),
                oTRANSEX.getArena_m3(),oTRANSEX.getArena2_m3(),oTRANSEX.getGravilla_m3(),oTRANSEX.getGrava_m3(), oTRANSEX.getAditivo1_m3(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo2_m3(),
                oTRANSEX.getAditivo3_m3(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo4_m3(),
                oTRANSEX.getAguatotal_m3(),oTRANSEX.getDiferencia_agua_m3(),

                /*SECOS*/
                oTRANSEX.getCemento1_secos(),oTRANSEX.getPsi_secos(),oTRANSEX.getFiller_secos(),oTRANSEX.getFibra1_secos(),
                oTRANSEX.getFibra2_secos(),oTRANSEX.getArena_secos(),oTRANSEX.getArena2_secos(),oTRANSEX.getGravilla_secos(),oTRANSEX.getGrava_secos(),
                oTRANSEX.getAditivo1_secos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo2_secos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo3_secos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo4_secos(),oTRANSEX.getAguatotal_secos(),
                oTRANSEX.getDiferencia_agua_secos(),

                /*HUMEDAD*/
                oTRANSEX.getCemento1_hu(),oTRANSEX.getPsi_hu(),oTRANSEX.getFiller_hu(),oTRANSEX.getFibra1_hu(),
                oTRANSEX.getFibra2_hu(),oTRANSEX.getArena_hu(),oTRANSEX.getArena2_hu(),oTRANSEX.getGravilla_hu(),oTRANSEX.getGrava_hu(),
                oTRANSEX.getAditivo1_hu(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo2_hu(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo3_hu(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo4_hu(),oTRANSEX.getAguatotal_hu(),oTRANSEX.getDiferencia_agua_hu(),

                /*HUMEDOS*/
                oTRANSEX.getCemento1_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getPsi_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getFiller_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getFibra1_humedos(),
                oTRANSEX.getFibra2_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getArena_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getArena2_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getGravilla_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getGrava_humedos(),
                oTRANSEX.getAditivo1_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo2_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo3_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getAditivo4_humedos(),oTRANSEX.getAguatotal_humedos(),
                oTRANSEX.getDiferencia_agua_humedos(),

                /*PESO MATERIAL*/
                oTRANSEX.getPeso_material(),

                /*OBSERVACIONES*/

                oTRANSEX.getObservacion1(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion2(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion3(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion4(),
                oTRANSEX.getObservacion5(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion6(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion7(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion8(),
                oTRANSEX.getObservacion9(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion10(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion11(),oTRANSEX.getObservacion12(),
            
                 /*MEDICIONES HORMIGON FRESCO*/   
                oTRANSEX.getCono_pedido(),oTRANSEX.getCono_obtenido(),oTRANSEX.getPeso_muestra(),oTRANSEX.getVolumen_tarro(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad(),
                oTRANSEX.getTemp_hormigon(),oTRANSEX.getAire_obtenido(),oTRANSEX.getVolumen_rendido(),oTRANSEX.getRendimiento(),
                oTRANSEX.getCemento_real(),oTRANSEX.getAgua_libre_real(),oTRANSEX.getRazon_ac(),oTRANSEX.getAgua_libre(),
                
                oTRANSEX.getAgua_absorcion(),oTRANSEX.getAgua_total(),oTRANSEX.getTemp_ambiente(),oTRANSEX.getHumedad_relativa(),oTRANSEX.getExudacion(),
                oTRANSEX.getSegregacion(),
                
                oTRANSEX.getFecha1(),oTRANSEX.getFecha2(),oTRANSEX.getFecha3(),oTRANSEX.getFecha4(),oTRANSEX.getFecha5(),oTRANSEX.getFecha6(),oTRANSEX.getFecha7(),
                oTRANSEX.getFecha8(),oTRANSEX.getFecha9(),oTRANSEX.getDias1(),oTRANSEX.getDias2(),oTRANSEX.getDias3(),oTRANSEX.getDias4(),oTRANSEX.getDias5(),
                oTRANSEX.getDias6(),oTRANSEX.getDias7(),oTRANSEX.getDias8(),oTRANSEX.getDias9(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad1(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad2(),
                oTRANSEX.getDensidad3(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad4(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad5(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad6(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad7(),oTRANSEX.getDensidad8(),
                oTRANSEX.getDensidad9(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura1(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura2(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura3(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura4(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura5(),
                oTRANSEX.getRuptura6(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura7(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura8(),oTRANSEX.getRuptura9(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta1(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta2(),
                oTRANSEX.getProbeta3(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta4(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta5(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta6(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta7(),oTRANSEX.getProbeta8(),
                oTRANSEX.getProbeta9(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia1_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia2_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia3_probeta(),
                oTRANSEX.getResistencia4_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia5_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia6_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia7_probeta(),
                oTRANSEX.getResistencia8_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia9_probeta(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia1_media(),oTRANSEX.getResistencia2_media(),
                oTRANSEX.getResistencia3_media(),oTRANSEX.getTiempo1_cono(),oTRANSEX.getTiempo2_cono(),oTRANSEX.getTiempo3_cono(),oTRANSEX.getAsentamiento1_cono(),
                oTRANSEX.getAsentamiento2_cono(),oTRANSEX.getAsentamiento3_cono(),oTRANSEX.getInicio(),oTRANSEX.getTermino(),oTRANSEX.getDelta(),oTRANSEX.getHora(),
                oTRANSEX.getVolumen());

            objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInsert);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "HP ingresado correctamente",
                "OPERACION EXITOSA",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            
            
            
    }
    
    
    
    
            
   this.mostrarDatos();
    
}
```

Comment: Declare a flag at start (`boolean done;`).  Set the flag inside the if portion (`done = true;`) and check the flag after the for loop `if (done) return;`.  If you want to cease at the first time condition is true then you can omit the flag and just add `return;` inside the if.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using the @Gardener comment, and i remove the "modelo.removeRow(i);" to keep showing the data in the jtable, thanks!!